# How to disable all the widgets in android device?

Tags: java, android, widget

I am trying to disable all the widgets from my device through my application.I am using the following to get the list of all the widgets but it does not get all the info for all the widgets,lets say I have 26 widgets in my phone but gets only 15 items in the list which gets disabled.

```
private static void disableAllWidgets(Context context)
    {
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> infoList = manager.getInstalledProviders();
        for (AppWidgetProviderInfo info : infoList)
        {
            String providerInfo = "" + info.provider;
            int startIndex = providerInfo.indexOf('{');
            int endIndex = providerInfo.indexOf('}');
            String[] parts = (providerInfo.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex)).split("/");
            String packageName = parts[0];
            String widgetProviderName = parts[1];
            try
            {
                mPackageManager = (PackageManager) context.getPackageManager();
                try
                {
                    mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(packageName, widgetProviderName), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(packageName, widgetProviderName), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

now my question is how can we disable the rest widgets which are not there in the list since i wanted to disable all the widgets.

Comment: First, ordinary SDK apps cannot disable components of other apps. Second, there is no requirement that everything described by a home screen as an app widget actually be implemented as an app widget. They could be simple features of the home screen itself. You cannot disable those.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes Iam making it as system app

Comment: some of the widgets that fall under shortcuts category that i am able to disable but again 2 to 3 widgets are left out